# BASH reading data from XML and copying it to certain fields in a text file

Tags: xml, bash, text

I have a specific problem where I can't seem to find the solution to.
I have two files. An XML file and a text file.

Snippet from XML file below:

```
<furnidata>
<roomitemtypes>
<furnitype id="13" classname="shelves_norja">
<revision>61856</revision>
<defaultdir>0</defaultdir>
<xdim>1</xdim>
<ydim>1</ydim>
<partcolors>
<color>#ffffff</color>
<color>#F7EBBC</color>
</partcolors>
<name>Boekenkast</name>
<description>Bewaar hier je frutsels en kunstboeken</description>
<adurl/>
<offerid>5</offerid>
<buyout>1</buyout>
<rentofferid>-1</rentofferid>
<rentbuyout>0</rentbuyout>
<bc>1</bc>
<excludeddynamic>0</excludeddynamic>
<customparams/>
<specialtype>1</specialtype>
<canstandon>0</canstandon>
<cansiton>0</cansiton>
<canlayon>0</canlayon>
<furniline>iced</furniline>
</furnitype>
```

Snippet from text file below:

```
["20_credits","20 Credits",""],["220c_100d","50 procent korting op 220 Credits","220 credits en diamanten voor de prijs van 110 credits! Aanbieding is 48 uur beschikbaar en beperkt tot √©√©n per persoon."],["22_credits","22 Credits",""],["25credit_prize_14","25 Credits!",""],["2credit_prize_14","2 Credits!",""],["3-giveaway3","3-giveaway3",""]
```

**My problem:**
It is my intention to copy each **classname=""** from the XML file to the first **""** between each **[]** where the name and description from the XML match the name (second "") and description (third "") from the text file. The problem is that some names and descriptions come twice or more. For example the combination "Boekenkast" and "Bewaar hier je frutsels en kunstboeken" comes a total of 7 times each with a different classname.

The XML is sorted by id, yet the text file is completely mixed up.

Any idea how to approach this with bash? I'm far from a scripting prodigy.

In case I wasn't clear enough explaining it here feel free to leave a reaction, I will update my question immediately.

Comment: It will help if you question will show the requested output for the given input file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's no neat one-liner to solve this, but here's my take.

You can use `jq` to iterate over the top-level array, query name & description from each nested 3-array, query the XML file for a `classname` attribute of `furnitype` items that have child nodes `name` & `description` with the values from JSON then update the JSON with that class name.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

IN_JSON=input.json
IN_XML=input.xml
OUT_JSON=output.json

cat $IN_JSON > $OUT_JSON
XML=$(cat $IN_XML)
JSON=$(cat $IN_JSON)

JSON_ITEMS_N=`echo "$JSON" | jq '.|length'`

for (( I=0; I<$JSON_ITEMS_N; I++ )) do
    (( $I % 10 == 0 )) && echo "Item $I"

    # Querying the name & description entries from the JSON list.
    XML_N=`echo "$JSON" | jq -cr .[$I][1]`
    XML_D=`echo "$JSON" | jq -cr .[$I][2]`

    # Querying the found values from the XML file.
    XML_CLASS=$(echo $XML | xpath -q -e "//furnitype[name=\"$XML_N\" and description=\"$XML_D\"]/@classname")
    for CN in ${XML_CLASS[@]}; do
        XML_CLASS=$CN
        # Using the first encountered classname.
        # Remove break to use the last one.
        break
    done
    XML_CLASS="${XML_CLASS}"
    XML_CLASS=${XML_CLASS#*\"}
    XML_CLASS=${XML_CLASS%\"}

    if [[ $XML_CLASS != "" ]]; then
        echo "Found '$XML_N' / '$XML_D', classname is $XML_CLASS"
        # Updating the entire input JSON and saving it right to the output file.
        # Although map() iterates over entire file contents, the if clause within map()
        # limits it to only the needed entries (those with proper name & desc).
        JSON=$(echo "$JSON" | jq -cr ". | map(if .[1]==\"$XML_N\" and .[2]==\"$XML_D\" then .[0]=\"$XML_CLASS\" else . end)")
    fi
done

echo -n "$JSON" > $OUT_JSON
```

Comment: I'm getting a couple of errors running the script:
- line 5: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
- Expected separator between values at line 1, column 5115
Also here is a pastebin link to part of the file. As you can see it consists only of [ ] and no { } https://pastebin.com/C3EVPYk2 So I suppose it crashed because it isn't a correct json file?

Comment: @NielsRex so it's a real JSON, not a JSON-like custom format. But it contains two separate arrays, which is not correct, and that was the issue. The script expects one array per input JSON file. I updated the script to account for real JSON format, it works with correct (having single top-level entity) files.

Comment: Alright. I noticed the json file is well... a bit broken but I can possibly fix that manually. Now I'm getting an error on the less than  < sign in the loop: "line 11: ((: I<100"  I have the latest bash version.

Comment: @NielsRex it happens because there are two separate arrays in your file (the one on pastebin), and `jq` returns lengths of both of them, so it's two lines. If you fix the file so it contains only one array (either by merging them together or moving to separate files), the script will work.

Comment: It fails when finding classnames where the same name and description are found more than once. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: I fixed the script so it doen't anymore. The `break` on #26 lets you choose which class name, first or last, to use.